# Properties of divisible modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, injective-module

I've got two questions concerning divisible modules that are defined as follows: Let $M$ be a $R$-module. $M$ is called *divisible* iff for all $r\neq 0$ the map $\phi_r :M \to M $ $m\mapsto rm$ is surjective.

Questions:
1) Is the map $\phi_r$ also injective?

[ANSWERED in the comments: Consider the $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.]

2) Is every injective $R$-module divisible? (I found this to be true over $R$ being PID or integers, but does it hold also for general $R$?)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you heard of Prüfer groups?

Comment: No, are they a counterexample to injectivity of $\phi_r$?

Comment: Yes, indeed (they are infinite $p$-groups which are divisible).

Comment: Even simpler, look at $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: Could you give an explicit example for that? I just dont see it...

Comment: Do you see that it is divisible? Note that any integer will annihilate some non-zero element.

Comment: Oh, thanks! So I have that non-zero element and 0 itself as a preimage for 0 :)

Comment: I've edited the question, because 1) is answered now.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a proof of the fact that a divisible module cannot be written as a finite union of proper submodules?